# graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: connection_resolver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'info'

Tags: python, django, graphql, django-permissions, graphene-django

I'm trying to set permissions for my django-graphql(graphene) project using [this](https://pypi.org/project/graphene-permissions/) package. According to it's doc, I have set the following configuration to control the `all_dormitories` query:

```
from graphene_permissions.mixins import AuthNode, AuthFilter
from graphene_permissions.permissions import AllowAuthenticated, AllowAny

class DormitoryNode(AuthNode, DjangoObjectType):
     permission_classes = (AllowAuthenticated,)

     class Meta:
          model = Dormitory
          filter_fields = {
               'name': ['exact', 'icontains', 'istartswith'],
               }
          interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

class AuthenticatedFilter(AuthFilter):
     permission_classes = (AllowAuthenticated,)

class DormitoriesQuery(graphene.ObjectType):
     all_dormitories = AuthenticatedFilter(DormitoryNode)
```

But when I send request to this query it responds as follows:

```
{
 "errors": [
    {
      "message": "connection_resolver() missing 1 required positional argument: 'info'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "allDormitories"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "allDormitories": null
  }
}
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with my code?

Note: I have replaced `AllowAuthenticated` with `AllowAny` and the response was the same.